# Load big image in osg

Tags: openscenegraph

i am using openscenegraph to show a bridge model.I use Texture2D to represent an image.Now,the problem is that the image is too large, about 1G .if i load the whole image at one time,it would be a waste of computer memory. I want to implement the effect similar to google map.Loading image of different quality according to distance of view sight. Is there any body know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You want to be using something like osgEarth, which handles all of that sort of thing, and basically is a Google Earth clone.

Alternately, Virtual Planet Builder does some of the tiling and paging that Google Maps/Earth do. osgEarth was designed as an enhancement to the capabilities in VPB.